# Android File Uploading to server

Tags: android, image, uploading

I want my app to timely check my photo folder. if new picture is available, upload it to the folder in the server. How to do it ? or any reading materials

Regards

Comment: you can do it using polling or push notification.

Answer (score 1):

It you're interested in discovering media changes it should be quite possible to implement a `SyncAdapter` for the "`media`" authority - whenever an update is made to the available media, e.g. a new MP3 or photo is discovered your `SyncAdapter` will be triggered and you can sync it with your remote folder.